# Binding not working in dynamically generated HTML

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I am creating chatbox, and that chat box is dynamically generated on click of contact.
In dynamically generated HTML I have a textarea to enter some text, here is the HTML

```html
<div class="chatboxinput">
  <textarea id="chatboxtextareaankur" class="chatboxtextarea" keydown.delegate="checkChatBoxInputKey($event, 'id', 'name')"></textarea>
</div>
```

But the method "checkChatBoxInputKey" is not executing on any key down event.
Please let me know how to solve this.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't work because Aurelia's view compiler doesn't have an opportunity to compile dynamically generated markup to find the bindings, etc.

Use the `if` binding to add/remove an element from the DOM.  Here's an example:

http://plnkr.co/edit/kBUz94?p=preview

```html
<template>
  <button click.delegate="showChatBox = true">Show Chat Box</button>

  <div if.bind="showChatBox" class="chatboxinput">
    <textarea id="chatboxtextareaankur" class="chatboxtextarea" keydown.delegate="checkChatBoxInputKey($event)"></textarea>
  </div>
</template>
```

```js
export class App {
  checkChatBoxInputKey(e) {
    console.log(e.which);
    return true;
  } 
}
```

Comment: thnx, its working but there should also some mechanism to manually apply binding like how we do in knockout.